# Cache read_html

Tags: r, caching, web-scraping, memoise

I tried to cache `read_html/xml2` to avoid flooding the server during development

```
library(digest)
library(xml2)
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org"
cache = digest(url)
if (file.exists(cache)) {
  cat("Reading from cache\n")
  html = readRDS(cache)
} else {
  #Sys.sleep(3)
  cat("Reading from web\n")
  html = xml2::read_html(url) 
  saveRDS(html, file = cache)
}
html
```

This fails, because only externalpointers are stored in the file which are no longer valid on re-run. The same problem occurs when I use `memoise` on `read_html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `as_list` and `as_xml_document` to convert back and forth.

```
library(digest)
library(xml2)
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org"
cache = digest(url)
if (file.exists(cache)) {
  cat("Reading from cache\n")
  html = as_xml_document(readRDS(cache))
} else {
  cat("Reading from web\n")
  html = read_html(url) 
  saveRDS(as_list(html), file = cache)
}
html
```

Alternatively, look into `read_xml` and `write_xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I gave up with it and do a cache on derived quantities. as_list(html) is TERRIBLY slow (1 Minute for the Wiki-Page), and I only find part of the attributes afterwards - looks like there is some loss in translation.